# How to cut polyhedron with a plane or bounding box?

Tags: cgal

Within a polyhedron, how do I obtain the handle to any edge that intersects a given plane (purpose is that I can further cut it with `CGAL::polyhedron_cut_plane_3`)?

I currently have this snippet but it doesn't work. I constructed this from pieces found in CGAL documentations and examples:

- [CGAL 4.14 - 3D Fast Intersection and Distance Computation (AABB Tree)](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/AABB_tree_2AABB_polyhedron_facet_intersection_example_8cpp-example.html)

```cpp
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Polyhedron;
typedef CGAL::AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive<Polyhedron> Primitive;
typedef CGAL::AABB_traits<Kernel, Primitive> Traits;

Polyhedron poly = load_obj(argv[1]); // load from file using a helper
Kernel::Plane_3 plane(1, 0, 0, 0);   // I am certain this plane intersects the given mesh

CGAL::AABB_tree<Traits> tree(faces(poly).first, faces(poly).second, poly);
auto intersection = tree.any_intersection(plane);
if (intersection) {
  if (boost::get<Kernel::Segment_3>(&(intersection->first))) {
    // SHOULD enter here and I can do things with intersection->second
  } else {
    // BUT it enters here
  }
} else {
  std::cout << "No intersection." << std::endl;
}
```

---

Edit on 9/9/2019:

I changed this title from the original *Old title: How to obtain the handle to some edge found in a plane-polyhedron intersection*. With the methods provided in `CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/clip.h`, it is unnecessary to use AABB_Tree to find intersection.

- To clip with one plane, one line is enough: `CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::clip(poly, plane);`
- To clip within some bounding box, as suggested by @sloriot, there is an internal function `CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::internal::clip_to_bbox`. Here is [an example](https://pastebin.com/r2EifyU8).

Comment: Instead of any_intersection() you have to call any_intersected_primitive()
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/classCGAL_1_1AABB__tree.html#a5e04790a20fe9868c68e51b95c06de31

Comment: I'm sure it can be done in this way but since I found a simpler alternative, I won't spend more time on figuring this out. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do it would be to use the function undocumented function `clip_to_bbox()` from the file `CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/clip.h` to turn a plane into a clipping bbox and call the function [`corefine()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__corefinement__grp.html#ga6447dee822aaf92016f34512ce0b3456) to embedded the plane intersection into your mesh. If you want to get the intersection edges, pass a edge constrained map to `corefine()` in the named parameters.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this header. To clip a mesh within bbox this is simple to use and works. Here is the snippet I used: https://pastebin.com/r2EifyU8.

Comment: If your goal was clipping with a bbox or an arbitray closed manifold mesh, there is an overload of [`clip()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__corefinement__grp.html#ga30082762ba2d947cba304e2884d96a99) that is working directly and that is documented. Note that you should at least use `CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel` instead of `CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>`.